# Calculate .length before or in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I am watching about optimisations and simple intellectual response.

In javascript and in most of time you speak about for loop.

If you find in internet. You can see many people saying that code is less efficient

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

}
```

than

```
var len = arr.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
}
```

Then i thought about it. It seems ok to say that because if you just read the code you will say in the 1rst code every time you go in loop you want to receive the length.

So i would like to answear to it with something practical.

If you find about javascript everything is object so you "can" use setter and getter ?

so i try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="abc">Hello</h1>
  <script>

    var eles=document.getElementsByClassName('abc');

    var tmp = eles.prototype.length;

    Object.defineProperty(eles, 'length', {
      get: function(e) {
        console.log("je suis la", this);
        return tmp.call(this);
      }
    })


    var len = eles.length;
    // for(i=0; i < eles.length;i++){
    // }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem i found here ATM is that i am in infinity loop.

Comment: "*simple intellectual response*"???

Comment: "*you find in internet many people saying*" …many things. And many of them outdated. Please post the links to where you found these.

Answer (score 0):

At first there is no prototype on an instance:

```
var tmp = eles.prototype.length;
```

`prototype` doesnt exist on `eles` and `length` doesnt exist on the prototype, it only exists on the instance itself. And you cannot get the reference to the underlying getter / setter as they are completely transparent. You could however:

```
 var number = eles.length;
```

And then inside the getter just return that number:

```
 return tmp;
```

But this is still bad for three reasons:

1) NodeLists are dynamic, so the length might change inbetween, which will cause range exceeds, and unexpected errors are bad.

2) You kill every inlining optimization every serious js engine would've done before. In most browsers `for(const el of array)` is actually way faster than fiddling with indexes.

3) It doesnt change anything as its the property lookup that is slow, not the getter itself.

Comment: I try to reformulate what you say. 
-1  think about a static nodelist.
-2 i am ok with indexes and not
- 3 i agree about the getter

What i want to proove here is the length is calculate one time in every loop ? even if you use the 1rst or the 2nd action ? And i dont know how to demonstrate it

Comment: and the problem of what you present for of is not working on IE